# MSDN Subscription ISO extraction

Tags: installation

What do you use to extract the contents of an ISO after you've downloaded it from MSDN Subscription?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

7-Zip

http://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: +1. As well as being able to look inside ISOs, 7zip is blindingly fast and *much* better compression than I ever get out of WinZip.

Answer (score 10):

I usually mount the ISO to a virtual CD/DVD drive.  I've used the following freeware packages at various times.  As far as I know these install no toolbars, spyware or other junk.  I currently usually use MagicISO's - pretty much just works.

I don't know what the situation is for these on Vista or x64 (I'm still largely on 32-bit WinXP).

- Microsoft's unsupported Virtual CD
  tool:

  http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/b/6/7b6abd84-7841-4978-96f5-bd58df02efa2/winxpvirtualcdcontrolpanel_21.exe
- MagicISO's MagicDisk

  http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-overview.htm
- SlySoft's Virtual CloneDrive:

  http://static.slysoft.com/SetupVirtualCloneDrive.exe

Of course, I can't vouch for any of these other than to say I've used them successfully - your mileage may vary.

Comment: +1 to the MS unsupported tool.  It seems to have trouble with mounting network shares, but if you map a drive letter, then even those seem to work.  It couldn't be more lightweight, so that's a plus.

Comment: MagicISO works fine on Vista - I use it.

Comment: Virtual CloneDrive worked successfully for me in a Windows 7 (64-bit) VM on Azure.

Answer (score 6):

To look what's in the ISO you can:

- mount ISO image as a drive
- burn ISO on a cd/dvd
- use [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/) to look at / extract the contents

Answer (score 5):

DaemonTools is a great free virtual drive that will mount ISO files

http://forum.daemon-tools.cc/download.php

Answer (score 2):

Alex Feinman's (free) [ISO Recorder](http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm) if I want to burn it.  [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/) if I want to just open it.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.imgburn.com/ is great free ISO burner, can also verify the burned disc.

Answer (score 0):

All the times I have done a DL the file was an ISO.

If your question is what to do with it: (i.e. you don't know what an iso file is)

You burn it to a CD/DVD.  That is a disk image.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the ISO, i'll either burn it to disc or mount it to a virtual drive and install from the virtual drive (not really an option if the ISO is an OS).

Comment: not strictly true.  If it is an os, sometimes the OS will have an option to copy install files to the drive first before it begins the actual install...this really only helps if you aren't going to be wiping the drive or have a second drive you can install from =\

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Vista, (I have found) a lot of the virtual drive emulators do not work on Vista, but one that has worked on Vista for me is [Softpedia's freeware Virtual CloneDrive.](http://www.softpedia.com/get/CD-DVD-Tools/Virtual-CD-DVD-Rom/Virtual-CloneDrive.shtml)

Comment: Virtual CloneDrive is made by SlySoft, not Softpedia

Comment: You must be using a different 'Virtual CloneDrive' than me. I've never heard of SlySoft, only have the Softpedia version (no mention of 'SlySoft' in the about).

Answer (score 0):

I use the free version of Alcohol 52% - it lets you mount the ISO's as virtual CD drives.  This works great in Windows 7, Vista, XP, and 2003 & 2008 versions of server.

You can download it here if you're interested - http://trial.alcohol-soft.com/en/